# How to get orderId from below array?

Tags: php

$receipt array give the below output. How to get orderId ?

pr($data); die;

to get orderId, $data['receipt']['orderId']; But its gives me error..

```
App\Model\Entity\PaymentDetail Object
(
    [id] => 4
    [user_id] => 4
    [company_id] => 5
    [receipt] => {"orderId":"GPA.3312-5688-8401-53436","packageName":"com.kenbar.mynus2","productId":"com.mynus2.subscription99","purchaseTime":1534914306517,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"gefffblagdakjleamfngklli.AO-J1Ow9Q5PncOoRk-oshlRBQ8kVqt3A4uIZuQi6InX7sr4bx2lNzjS-VjOXyMIwkl2G-afrI0fzoVLEADNZP2RWekoxwe4ko1M884JALYhaZsxo44U9DshbKJxbDNQHcCx9_z0yQpxc","autoRenewing":true}

)
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php

Comment: you can convert `[receipt]` into array using `$x = json_decode(PaymentDetail->receipt, true)`; then you can access it using `$x['orderId']`

Comment: Hi Alive to die ..yes, i have tried this, but its give me error : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Try given answers. you will get the solution

Answer (score 2):

```
$orderJson = json_decode(data['receipt'],true);
print_r($orderJson['orderId']);
```

As `data['receipt']` contains a JSON string you need to parse it externally before consuming it as an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$order_id = json_decode($data->reciept, true)["orderId"];
```

Comment: You'll need to pass `true` as the second argument to `json_decode()` to get an associative array

Answer (score 0):

```
$orderId=json_decode($your_array->receipt);


echo $orderId->orderId;
```

You have a `json` as a string in your `stdClass` object field so you need to decode it first before you access it.

The above code will work for you.